# How do I create a custom panel that will append/import mesh files from blend files with custom preview icons?

Tags: python, scripting

I want to create something similar to this where I can have custom thumbnails for the mesh file that will be appended/imported from another blend file.

[image]

```
    import os
import re
import bpy
from bpy.props import *
import bpy.utils.previews
from bpy.types import WindowManager


# Append
class OBJECT_OT_AddButton(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "add.object"
    bl_label = "Add Object"

    def execute(self, context):
        selected_preview = bpy.data.window_managers["WinMan"].my_previews
        category = context.scene.grass.cat

        # Append Particle System
        bpy.ops.wm.append (directory = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "Blends" + os.sep + category + ".blend" + os.sep + "ParticleSettings/"), filepath=category + ".blend", filename=selected_preview)

        return{'FINISHED'}


# Update
def update_category(self, context):
    enum_previews_from_directory_items(self, context)


# Drop Down Menu
class Categories(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    mode_options = [
        ("Grass", "Grass", '', 0),
        ("Weeds", "Weeds", '', 1)
        ]

    cat = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        items=mode_options,
        description="Select a Category",
        default="Grass",
        update=update_category
    )


# Generate Previews
def enum_previews_from_directory_items(self, context):

    category = context.scene.grass.cat

    # Icons Directory
    directory = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "Icons" + os.sep + category)

    # EnumProperty Callback
    enum_items = []

    if context is None:
        return enum_items

    wm = context.window_manager

    # Get the Preview Collection (defined in register func)
    pcoll = preview_collections["main"]

    if directory == pcoll.my_previews_dir:
        return pcoll.my_previews

    print("Scanning directory: %s" % directory)

    if directory and os.path.exists(directory):
        # Scan the Directory for PNG Files
        image_paths = []
        for fn in os.listdir(directory):
            if fn.lower().endswith(""):
                image_paths.append(fn)

        # For each image in the directory, load the thumb unless it has already been loaded
        for i, name in enumerate(image_paths):
            # Generate a Thumbnail Preview for a File.
            filepath = os.path.join(directory, name)

            if filepath in pcoll:
                enum_items.append((name, name, "", pcoll[filepath].icon_id, i))
            else:
                thumb = pcoll.load(filepath, filepath, 'IMAGE')
                enum_items.append((name, name, "", thumb.icon_id, i))

    pcoll.my_previews = enum_items
    pcoll.my_previews_dir = directory
    return pcoll.my_previews


# Panel
class PreviewsPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    # Create a Panel in the Tool Shelf
    bl_category = "Edger"
    bl_label = "Grass Free"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'

    # Draw
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        wm = context.window_manager

        # Drop Down Menu
        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(context.scene.grass, "cat", text="Category")

        # Previews
        row = layout.row()
        row.template_icon_view(wm, "my_previews", show_labels=True)

        # Add Button
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("add.object", icon="ZOOMIN", text="Add")

preview_collections = {}

#####################################################################

# Register
def register():

    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

    WindowManager.my_previews_dir = StringProperty(
            name = "Folder Path",
            subtype = 'DIR_PATH',
            default = "")

    WindowManager.my_previews = EnumProperty(
            items = enum_previews_from_directory_items)

    pcoll = bpy.utils.previews.new()
    pcoll.my_previews_dir = ""
    pcoll.my_previews = ()

    preview_collections["main"] = pcoll
    bpy.types.Scene.grass = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=Categories)


# Unregister
def unregister():

    del WindowManager.my_previews

    for pcoll in preview_collections.values():
        bpy.utils.previews.remove(pcoll)
    preview_collections.clear()

    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

    del bpy.types.Scene.grass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: What have you got so far, what have you tried and where did it fail? Could you post some example code snippets?

Comment: http://www.3d-wolf.com/uploads/2/9/9/4/29944523/grass_free.zip

Comment: It's a free addon by "Wolf" that utilizes blender files for libraries for some grass objects, I just can figure out about how he did that, you can download the script and check it out.

Comment: Is that code that you wrote or is that from the mentioned addon?

Comment: It is from the addon, I can't get it into my grips, there are two blend files from which the addon imports stuff, I can understand what he meant by context.scene.grass.cat, please can you check out the file and maybe give me some answers.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, your question is either too broad or you seem to be biting more than you can chew. How is it different from the addon you show us? Could you please edit your question and rephrase it to focus on what you don't understand or what you want want to achieve, perhaps show us code that **you wrote** instead?